# Xiaomi Redmi 7 not working with USB in the IDE

Tags: android, android-studio

I have OS Catalina, Android Studio 3.5.1 and mobile phone Xiaomi Redmi 7A in order to install and run app in development without emulator, but I cannot connect through USB, EVEN IF I HAVE the USB Debugging already enabled, and also default USB configuration as File Transfer, I also asume I don´t need any USB drivers.

As you can see in the picture below, the unit is being recognized by Android studio but it does not work, Error coming back is " Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi 7A. Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed. Installation failed due to: 'device '3aa555fe0106' not found"

Please any help is welcome,

[image]

Comment: Can you disable insta run and try to install the app ?

Comment: AS 3.5.1 Instant run is changed to "Apply changes", no way to disable, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I did lots of testing, even with Stackoverflow proposed solutions, both with Xiaomi Redmi and with Huawei Y9, they did not work for me in anyway to run apps from Android Studio 3.5.1, while other phone brands like Alcatel or even ZTE blade did work with no problem just with activating USB debugging, my conclusion so far is that they get UI layers on top of Android from both manufacturers Xiaomi and Huawei that make it so difficult, so better switch to other brands for runing and testing in development mode